# session start without locking? or an workaround?

Tags: php, session

I have done some research about session start and why it locked all my other ajax request.
I found out that the user's session is locked until the page is done executing or session_write_close() is called.

with session_set_save_handler you can set your own handlers for session, but i don't know how it works and how i can NOT lock sessions and only read it.

Does someone have an example on session_set_save_handler?
Or is there an other workaround for read-only sessions / unlocked sessions?

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Using database to save PHP sessions avoid locking of ajax requests. session_set_save_handler allows that.

You will need to create a class with open, close, read, write, destroy, gc methods similar to this:

```
        /**
         * DBSession
         */
        class DBSession
        {

            /**
             * Db Object
             */
            private $db;

            public function __construct(){

                 $this->db = new DB; //initialise in your database connection object
            }

            /**
             * Open
             */
            public function open()
            {
                // If successful
                if ($this->db) {
                    // Return True
                    return true;
                }
                // Return False
                return false;
            }

            /**
             * Close
             */
            public function close()
            {
                // Close the database connection
                // If successful
                if ($this->db->close()) {
                    // Return True
                    return true;
                }
                // Return False
                return false;
            }

            /**
             * Read
             */
            public function read($id)
            {
                // Set query
                $this->db->query('SELECT data FROM sessions WHERE id = :id');

                // Bind the Id
                $this->db->bind(':id', $id);

                // Attempt execution
                // If successful
                if ($this->db->execute()) {
                    // Save returned row
                    $row = $this->db->single();
                    // Return the data
                    return $row['data'];
                } else {
                    // Return an empty string
                    return '';
                }
            }

            /**
             * Write
             */
            public function write($id, $data)
            {
                // Create time stamp
                $access = time();

                // Set query  
                $this->db->query('REPLACE INTO sessions VALUES (:id, :access, :data)');

                // Bind data
                $this->db->bind(':id', $id);
                $this->db->bind(':access', $access);
                $this->db->bind(':data', $data);

                // Attempt Execution
                // If successful
                if ($this->db->execute()) {
                    // Return True
                    return true;
                }

                // Return False
                return false;
            }

            /**
             * Destroy
             */
            public function destroy($id)
            {
                // Set query
                $this->db->query('DELETE FROM sessions WHERE id = :id');

                // Bind data
                $this->db->bind(':id', $id);

                // Attempt execution
                // If successful
                if ($this->db->execute()) {
                    // Return True
                    return true;
                }

                // Return False
                return false;
            }

            /**
             * Garbage Collection
             */
            public function gc($max)
            {
                // Calculate what is to be deemed old
                $old = time() - $max;

                // Set query
                $this->db->query('DELETE * FROM sessions WHERE access < :old');

                // Bind data
                $this->db->bind(':old', $old);

                // Attempt execution
                if ($this->db->execute()) {
                    // Return True
                    return true;
                }

                // Return False
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Then to start your session you can:

```
$dbSession = new DBSession();

session_set_save_handler(
  array($dbSession, "open"),
  array($dbSession, "close"),
  array($dbSession, "read"),
  array($dbSession, "write"),
  array($dbSession, "destroy"),
  array($dbSession, "gc")
);

session_start();
```

Alternately, you can move the session_set_save_handler call and session_start() to the constructor of your DBSession class. In that case you can simply initiate an instance of DBSession at the beginning of your script.

Actually, the PHP manual has already got some examples:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php